# How to make my wordpress menu always on top

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

This code controls the main menu of my site.
Currently it's set to if I scroll down, it will disappear, and when scrolling up, it will appear.

I want it to be always displayed on top whenever I scroll.

Thanks for your help.

```
var $fixed_enabled = jQuery("#main-nav.fixed-enabled");
if( $fixed_enabled.length > 0 ){
    jQuery( '#theme-header' ).imagesLoaded(function() {
        jQuery(function(){
            var navScroll_1  = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
            var headerHeight = $fixed_enabled .offset().top;

            $window.scroll(function() {
                var navScroll_2 = jQuery(document).scrollTop();

                if (navScroll_2 > headerHeight){ $fixed_enabled.addClass('fixed-nav'); } 
                else { $fixed_enabled.removeClass('fixed-nav');}

                if (navScroll_2 > navScroll_1){ $fixed_enabled.removeClass('fixed-nav-appear');} 
                else { $fixed_enabled.addClass('fixed-nav-appear');}                

                navScroll_1 = jQuery(document).scrollTop(); 
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This behavior is called [scroll then fix](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/), basically after scrolling to certain level you set to fixed at the top the header. We need you to add your css classes to see what is going on with your site. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response ...css is here https://jsfiddle.net/hafizc007/r28zkwkw/

Comment: Please provide a full code exemplifying the problem you have so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

just remove or comment this css, line 496:

```
.fixed-nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: -90px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 9999;
        opacity: 0.95;
        -webkit-transition: top .5s;
           -moz-transition: top .5s;
             -o-transition: top .5s;
                transition: top .5s;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                box-shadow: 0 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies...fixed by

```
if( $fixed_enabled.length > 0 ){
    jQuery( '#theme-header' ).imagesLoaded(function() {
        jQuery(function(){
            var navScroll_1  = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
            var headerHeight = $fixed_enabled .offset().top;

            $window.scroll(function() {
                var navScroll_2 = jQuery(document).scrollTop();

                if (navScroll_2 > headerHeight){ $fixed_enabled.addClass('fixed-nav fixed-nav-appear'); } 
                else { $fixed_enabled.removeClass('fixed-nav');}

            });
        });
    });
}
```